# Opengl glclipdistance vs glclipplane

Tags: opengl, clipping

What is difference between gl clipdistance and clipplane?
 Which will be effective for clipping? Is clip plane is contrained to normalised device coordinates ie. From -0.1 to 1.0.

Comment: -0.1? Do you mean -1.0?

Comment: You should also clearify about which methods you are talking. I assume you mean the glsl variable `gl_ClipDistance` and the OpenGL method `glClipPlane`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are refering to the OpenGL method `glClipPlane` and the glsl variable `gl_ClipDistance`: Those two are not directly related.

`glClipPlane` controls clipping planes in the fixed-function pipeline and is deprecated.

`gl_ClipDistance` is the modern version and is set from inside the shader. It has to contain the distance of the current vertex to a clip-plane. OpenGL does in this case not know anything about the clipplane itself, since the only relevant value are the distances to this planes.

The values of the plane (in both cases) are technically not constrained to any range, but in practice only planes intersecting the [-1, 1] cube will have any effect, since clipping against the unit cube still happens.